# How to compress the initial text/html request?

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, deflate

I'm using the following line in my .htaccess file to enable compression:

`AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript text/javascript application/json image/svg+xml image/jpeg`

This works fine except for the initial html request. Is there a way to compress the html as well?

This is what my request looks like:

**Response Header**

`Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.21`

**Request  Headers**

`Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de-DE;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable mod\_deflate for PHP files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835818/how-do-i-enable-mod-deflate-for-php-files)

Comment: I'm not struggling with enabling mod_deflate in general, just for the html request.